# Extend the data source selection of pivot table to the last row of an excel using python and refresh the pivot table

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, pywin32

I am automating some of my excel tasks using python.

I have a pivot table which takes values from an excel sheet. Data gets appended to the particular excel sheet every week, but the pivot table does not get refreshed automatically because of which, each time, I have to go to the excel sheet and give the last row number in **Change data source** option. Is there any way to automatically update the pivot table using python, more specifically using **pywin32**.

This is the code I tried:

def refresh_pivot_tables():

```
excel_app = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel_app.Interactive = False
excel_app.Visible = False
excel_app.DisplayAlerts = False
xlBook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(main_file)
ws = xlBook.Worksheets['Summary']
ws.Unprotect()  # IF protected
pivotCount = ws.PivotTables().Count
print("pivot count is",pivotCount)

for j in range(1, pivotCount + 1):
    ws.PivotTables(j).PivotCache().Refresh()

# Put protection back on
#ws.Protect(DrawingObjects=True, Contents=True, Scenarios=True, AllowUsingPivotTables=True)
xlBook.Close(SaveChanges=1)

del xlBook

excel_app.Quit()
del excel_app
```

Comment: Recommend you write out some of your code that you've attempted. So far it looks like you're just asking someone else to do the work for you.

Comment: I have added the part of code I found In Stack Overflow. It refreshes the Pivot Table. But the issue still remains and I have to give the row number manually